# Finding out if two rectangles intersect

Tags: c++

This is a homework assignment, so I'm mostly asking for a nudge in the right direction. I've figured out the majority of the problem. We have a Rectangle class, whose rectangles are defined by the x and y coordinates in a Point class. The one part I'm stuck on is figuring out if the two rectangles intersect. I've done some research, and came upon this:

http://silentmatt.com/rectangle-intersection/

That helps me with how it would need to be done. But I can't seem to implement it in the way that our teacher had it setup in the problem overview:

```
//This method returns true if this rectangle intersects with another rectangle (which is provided as a parameter)
bool intersects(Rectangle);
```

The intersects function only takes one parameter, that is of the Rectangle class. The call to it in main is something like this:

```
rec1.intersects(rec2);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to implement the actual function, though. I've already defined the points for both rec1 and rec2 with setters, but I can't seem to figure out how to access those points with the function that only accepts the one parameter. Because, in the example above, I can access the x and y points for rec2, but I can't with rec1.

Any tips on how to proceed?

EDIT: I think part of my problem is just how this was implemented. Here's what we have in the Rectangle class:

```
private:
Point lowerLeftCorner;
Point upperRightCorner;
```

And then he had us setup get and set functions in the Point class to set the points for lowerLeftCorner and upperRightCorner.

The problem is when I'm in the intersect function, I can ONLY (unless I'm missing something) use the get functions for the parameter (rectangle2) and not for the first rectangle (rectangle1).

If I was able to pass both rectangles as parameters, I could use the given examples to solve this. It's being able to find the values of x and y for the first rectangle that's giving me trouble.

EDIT: Robert's info helped me figure out how to do it using "this". Here's what I ended up with which seems to work well. It's probably not the best, I am still pretty new to programming.

```
bool Rectangle::intersects(Rectangle rec2) {
    return ( getupperX() > rec2.getlowerX() &&
    getlowerX() < rec2.getupperX() &&
    getupperY() > rec2.getlowerY() &&
    getlowerY() < rec2.getupperY());
    }
}
```

Seems to have worked for all the values I've tested!

Comment: Start by learning what "this" is in c++

Comment: Thanks, that helped me figure it out.

Comment: Your solution is `if (condition) return true; else return false;` What does the value of `condition` have to be for the `return true` to occur? What's the value of `condition` when you `return false`? Is there a way you can do with out the `if-else`?

Comment: bames53: I just edited the post to be more in line with what Pubby suggested. Does that look better?

Comment: Nate, it's also worth noting that while you CAN say this->getupperX() and this->getlowerX() etc, you can also just saying getupperX() and getlowerX(). Either way is basically the same, but the "this->" is implied inside of member functions. Do whatever is more clear for you, but "this->" is commonly omitted when referring to member variables, and the "this" keyword is generally used for when you're referring to the actual object itself.

Comment: I did try that at first, but for some reason it didn't work, so I thought I needed this->. If that's not needed, then I probably made a mistake somewhere else. I'll try it again with the "this->" when I get home today. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I went ahead and edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, if you're inside a **member** function of class, you have access to the **member** variables of that class implicitly.

So if you had

```
struct Rectangle 
{
  Point UpperLeft;
  Point LowerRight;
  bool intersects(Rectangle);
}
```

Then within the *intersects()* function, because it is a member of the class, you can access member variables of that class, like this:

```
Rectangle::intersects(Rectangle rhs)
{
  // So the second UpperLeft here is a member of "this" instance of the class
  if(rhs.UpperLeft < UpperLeft)
    return true;
}
```

*That function won't actually detect intersection, but that's how you would access all the points.*

So if you had:

```
Rectangle rect_a;
Rectangle rect_b;
rect_a.intersects(rect_b);
```

Then you would be calling **rect_a**'s *intersects()* function, so it would be "this" in the example above, where **rect_b** would be **rhs**

EDIT: 
Alternatively, in your example above, you could write something like

```
Rectangle::intersects(Rectangle rhs)
{
  if(rhs.GetLowerLeft() < GetLowerLeft())
    return true;
}
```

And the second GetLowerLeft() would be called on "this"

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I think that should be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
bool Rectangle::intersects(Rectangle r) {
  return
    (x1 < r.x2
  && x2 > r.x1
  && y1 < r.y2
  && y2 > r.y1);
}
```

If you want to use get functions then use them:

```
bool Rectangle::intersects(Rectangle r) {
  return
    (this->getX1() < r.getX2();
  // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps...I guess my biggest problem now is getting the values of x and y for rectangle1 within the intersects function. I've edited my first post.

Comment: @Nate The code I posted is fully working. x1 refers to the member of the calling object.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I had never used "this" before, but when I figured out how to implement it things worked flawlessly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Pubby gave one possible case for this problem.

If you really want to work through it, try looking at it in the 1-dimensional case first, 2 lines.  You'll find 3-5ish cases:

Overlap on left side.
Overlap on right side.
Both left endpoint coordinates are the same
Both right endpoint coordinates are the same
Both left and both right coordinates are the same (Lines are same length and same coordinates)

Then try to extend that out to a two-dimensional object.  Pubby's example should get you started well.